# How can I confirm if my CentOS server supports multiple CPUs?

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, linux-kernel

CentOS 5.8 | VMWare

I've got a server running a hardened version of CentOS 5.8. I've been using a single CPU on it and am planning to add another (via vmware).

When I run uname, I see SMP which leads me to believe that the system is already using the multi-cpu kernel:

```
[root@foobox ~]# uname -a
Linux box.foo.int 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 04:17:30 EST    
2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

However if I check, /boot/grub/grub.conf I see:

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.18-308.1.1.el5)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 ro root=LABEL=/ clocksource=tsc noapic nolapic
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-308.1.1.el5.img
title CentOS (2.6.18-308.1.1.el5PAE)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-308.1.1.el5PAE ro root=LABEL=/ clocksource=tsc noapic nolapic
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-308.1.1.el5PAE.img
title CentOS-base (2.6.18-308.1.1.el5)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 ro root=LABEL=/ clocksource=tsc noapic nolapic
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-308.1.1.el5.img
```

Should I see SMP somewhere in the grub.conf file? Does this mean that the server is running a kernel that does NOT support multiple CPUs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the seperate SMP kernel is a thing of the past. That is all compiled in stock now a days. Add the cpu in vmware and run the following command

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

That will list the 2nd cpu once you reboot after adding it.